How does a rotating system behave as mass varies?
Imagine you have two masses, $m_1$ and $m_2$ rigidly attached to each other and rotating about this system’s COM at some constant $\omega$. Now, suppose the rigid connection between the two masses is cut. My question is how will the system now behave. How will the rotational velocities of each mass ($\omega_1$, $\omega_2$)  compare to each other and to the original speed?
In thinking about the problem, my intuition leads me to think that the location of the COM is important. Suppose you had two ice skaters holding hands rotating around their center of mass (assume right between them). I can imagine that when the separate hands they will go off in straight lines and no longer rotate.
But in a different thought experiment, if one of the ice skaters is much much heavier than the other, and thus the COM is biased towards him, when they let go of each other, I can imagine that the lighter will head off into a straight line with no rotational speed while the heavier will continue to rotate now at a faster speed due to conservation of angular momentum.
EDIT:
To make this question more clear, the two masses are not point masses and can have spin angular momentum.

Have you thought about conservation of momentum in your analysis? Regardless of how heavy the second mass is, the COM will never be at the center of the heavier mass.

Yes, I’m aware that in certain circumstances both masses will move translationally, but the question refers to the angular velocity.

Independent of the mass the two parts will fly in tangential direction  and with constant speed so momentum and angular momentum and center of mass are conserved.

I don’t know if that’s necessarily true if the axis of rotation through the COM is also inline with the masses. There would be no translation velocity.

@AlexVaughan it's just Newton's first law.

I agree, but if you have a system in which the axis of rotation aligns with the rigid connection, then there is not translational motion when the connection is broken.

This answer is valid for point masses, but the question is asking about masses of finite size that can revolve about their own center of mass.

@Carmeister The first paragraph, which contains the actual question, does not specify the size of the masses, making the question unclear.


But in a different thought experiment, if one of the ice skaters is
much much heavier than the other, and thus the COM is biased towards
him, when they let go of each other, I can imagine that the lighter
will head off into a straight line with no rotational speed while the
heavier will continue to rotate now at a faster speed due to
conservation of angular momentum.

The intuitively difficult bit is that the lighter ice-skater that travels off in a straight line still has angular velocity and maintains angular momentum!

Angular momentum for a point particle is given by $mrv$ where $v$ is the tangential velocity orthogonal to the radius.
At $\text{P}_1$ the angular momentum is $L_1 = m\times r_1 \times v$.
At $\text{P}_2$ the angular momentum is $L_2 = m\times r_2 \times u$.
$r_2$ is greater than $r_1$, but $u$ is smaller than $v$, and it works out that $L_1 = L_2$ and angular momentum is conserved even when flying off in a straight line. We can also express angular momentum in terms of moment of inertia ($I$) and angular velocity ($\omega$) so that:
At $\text{P}_1$ the angular momentum is $L_1 = I_1 \Omega_1 = (m r_1^2)\times (v/r_1) $.
At $\text{P}_2$ the angular momentum is $L_2 = I_2 \Omega_2 = (m r_2^2)\times (u/r_2) $.
The moment of inertia ($mr^2$) increases as the object flies off in a straight line, but the angular velocity ($v/r$) is also decreasing by just the right amount, and angular momentum is conserved.
When considering both objects at the same time, both objects rotate around a common barycentre ($\text{B}$), and no matter how heavy one of the objects is, the barycentre is never exactly at the centre of the heavier object.

When the connection is broken, both objects fly off in opposite directions but parallel to each other so that the total linear momentum remains zero and is conserved. The heavier object moves off slower in a straight line than the lighter object.

However, this is very counterintuitive that the masses will slow down as
time goes on.

I think you misunderstood something in my answer above. When an orbiting object is cut loose, it continues indefinitely with the same tangential velocity (red $\color{red}{\vec{v}}$ vectors in the first diagram) at the instant it cuts loose. What is slowing is the component that is at right angles to the radial line pointing at the centre of rotation (green $\color{green}{\vec{u}}$ vector). This means the angular velocity of a pair of objects around the original centre of rotation is continually slowing down as they move away in a straight line (while maintaining constant angular momentum) about that same point.

I see. I thought that for the general case (not necessarily point
masses), the orbital angular momentum would be converted into spin
angular momentum (masses spin around their own centers of mass). But
it appears that this is not true.

There are situations where spin angular momentum is converted to orbital angular momentum, but that is not the case here. Total angular momentum (spin plus orbital) is always conserved. If one reduces, the other must increase. In the case of the two skaters, when they let go of each other, the orbital angular momentum remains constant, so the spin angular momentum of the individual skaters also has to stay constant. The spin angular velocity of the skaters around their own axes is the same as the orbital angular velocity when they were joined and remains the same as they move away in straight lines.

I see. I thought that for the general case (not necessarily point masses) the orbital angular momentum would be converted into spin angular momentum (masses spin around their own centers of mass). But it appears that this is not true. However, this is very counterintuitive that the masses will slow as time goes on. What force is causing this to happen? Also, in the traditional sense, the masses, after they separate, are not rotating even though they have constant angular momentum, they have some effective angular velocity? Does your answer above apply for non-point mass situations?

@AlexVaughan I have extended my answer to address the issues you ask about in your comment.

"There are situations where spin angular.... but that is not the case here." Why? Suppose I had very large mass and a very small mass (a planet and a small section of earth connected together rigidly). The barycenter of the system is inside the larger mass and the system spins/orbits/rotates around this center. Once these masses detach, I would expect the masses to move in opposite directions by momentum conservation as described, but I would also expect the large mass to spin about its own COM and likewise for the smaller mass. Hence, the orbital momentum has converted to spin momentum.


How will the rotational velocities of each mass ($\omega1, \omega2$) compare to each other and to the original speed?

After the connection is severed, you have each mass now with no external forces or torques.   Therefore it has no linear or angular acceleration and the linear and angular velocities of both components remain identical to what they were when the break happened.
With different masses, the two might have a different distance from the COM and therefore a different translational velocity.   But since the object was rigid, all parts would have the same angular velocity.

I can imagine that when the separate hands they will go off in straight lines and no longer rotate.

As the skaters were rotating before the separation, what torque would be applied that would cause them to stop rotating?

@user721108 There was probably a misunderstanding on my part as the question is unclear. I was referring to the orbital angular velocity of the masses about the system's COM rather than the spin angular velocity of each object about its own center of mass (point masses don't spin by definition). The former decreases; the latter doesn't. The centers of mass of the two individual objects, together with the COM of the system, do indeed form a straight line even after separation. In any case there is no contradiction as the angular momenta of both objects remain constant in time.

@VincentThacker i think "the former decreases" is wrong. It should be "the former instantaneously stops"

@user721108 Not true. The angular velocity about the system's COM (which is fixed in space) gradually decreases and approaches zero. The general definition of angular velocity of a point about a given origin is $\mathrm{d}\theta/\mathrm{d}t$ where $\theta$ is the polar angle coordinate of that point w.r.t. that origin.

@user721108 The first paragraph of my answer explains why the orbital angular velocity of the system does not go to zero when the skaters fly off in straight lines, but it does gradually slow down as mentioned by Vincent Thacker.

@VincentThacker & KDP you're right, intuitively difficult for sure ! Thanks


How will the rotational velocities of each mass (ω1, ω2) compare to each other and to the original speed?

Prior to the separation, the entire system was rotating, as a rigid body, at a constant angular velocity.
At the separation, no torques were applied to the system or to the separating parts of the system.
After the separation therefore, the now individual parts of the system will continue to rotate as they did before, with their original angular velocity. The angular momentum of the entire system will also be the same as it was before.

In the case described above, the objects rotate around their centre of mass. Is it necessary to think about why they rotate in the first place? It is because there is a force acting on both bodies.
Consider the case of the two skaters holding hands. If one applies, say, a force $F$ on the other person, one also experiences the same force, just opposite in direction. Taking both the skaters as a system and ignoring friction, we see the net external force of the system is $0$. (The weight gets cancelled by the normal force of the ground). This force is normal to the velocity vector and hence changes its direction. As soon as the skaters lose contact, this force ceases to exist. Now, the velocity vector will not change its direction, and both skaters will continue to move with constant velocity.
Notice how the mass of the skaters doesn't matter in the entire argument; neither does the position of the centre of mass.
Regarding the conservation of angular momentum:
It is not necessary for a body to execute rotational motion or to have angular velocity or angular momentum about a given axis or point.
Therefore, both the skaters going in a straight line won't affect the conservation of angular momentum.
$$\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{P} \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbf{L} = I \boldsymbol{\omega}.$$
Both of these equations represent the same thing.

But in a different thought experiment, if one of the ice skaters is much much heavier than the other, and thus the COM is biased towards him when they let go of each other, I can imagine that the lighter will head off into a straight line with no rotational speed while the heavier will continue to rotate now at a faster speed due to conservation of angular momentum.

There is a slight correction I would like to make in your line of thought. As described above, there is no net external force on the system; hence, the centre of mass remains at rest. Now, if what you say were to happen, would the centre remain at rest? Think.
After a very long time, the lighter skater would be very far away while the heavier one would remain close to the vicinity of the initial point of rotation. The centre of mass moves! Hence, this is impossible.
Note:
In one case, this can be possible. It happens so that the mass of one of the bodies taken into consideration is incomparable to the other. For instance, the electron and nucleus. The lighter body can shoot off while the heavier one barely moves. But in your problem, this clearly can't be the case.
I would recommend you try a few problems from any standard textbook to clear your thoughts.
Thank you.
